# Disable "flashed" search result in Atom?

Tags: macos, search, atom-editor

Is there a way to disable the "flash" effect for search results in Atom? I'm running Atom 1.60.0 x64 on macOS Monterey.

When I search on a work and Atom finds it, Atom highlights the word with a flash effect. In my editor, the word is higlighted with a very dark gray and then fades to a light gray. To my eyes, this is an annoyance. The first image below shows the initial flashed highlight. The second shows the final, fade-to highlight.

[image: Initial flashed higlight.]
[image: final highlight]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atom is built upon the Chrome browser, meaning its interface is created with HTML and CSS.

I haven't been able to find the exact CSS selector to disable the effect. If you don't mind the side-effect of all animations and transitions within the Atom window being disabled, you can try adding the following to your [Atom style-sheet](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#style-tweaks):

```css
* {
  animation: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

Otherwise, it hopefully helps you on your way!